# How to write an image to a path in swift 3.0

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using core data to store a url to an image that was taken from the imagepicker.

So far I have the following:

```
    let tempImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage

    let image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(tempImage!, 0.2)

    let path = try! FileManager.default.url(for: FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, in: FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let imageName = UUID().uuidString + ".jpg"

    let aPath = path.path

    let imagePath = (aPath as NSString).appendingPathComponent(imageName)
```

The result is now I have a path as a string to save in core data. 
But how do I write the image to the path?
I was trying to use:

```
   let result = image!.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

But i get an error saying value of type data has no member writeToFile. Is there another way to do it in swift 3.0?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Just move the original file instead of converting it UIImageJPEGRepresentation and saving it again

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In Swift 3, `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` creates `Data` instead of `NSData`. You can use `write` instead of `writeToFile`.

You should be able to use:

```
image.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .atomic)
```

and write out your image data `image` to a file at `path`. Notice that it uses a URL instead of a string file path, and the options parameter has changed.

Comment: Thanks for this, I ended up having to rewrite it a bit work with my code, but you pointed me in the right direction! :)

Answer (score 4):

With help from Dylansturg,

I was able to rewrite my code to work. Here is the code for future reference:

```
do {
   let result = try image?.write(to: path, options: .atomic)
} catch let error { 
    print(error) 
}
```

Comment: Just move the original file instead of converting it UIImageJPEGRepresentation and saving it again

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to convert the UIImage object to NSData object, then follow this link to write the NSData object to a path:

https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdata/1408033-writetofile?language=objc